# How to improve the performance of app with a Google Map in it built with sencha touch and phoneGap?

Tags: android, performance, cordova, sencha-touch

I have built an app which contains a google js map with sencha touch and phoneGap ,
But its performance is not good(At least in my Samsumg Galaxy9000) it takes almost half a minute to load the whole map,
BTW,I have lazy loaded the Google Map Js library
How to improve its performance?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the excellent libraries here: [github.com/libbybaldwin/GMap-Demo-App](https://github.com/libbybaldwin/GMap-Demo-App)

Most of my map issues have gona away since I started using this library.